# Кэширование изображений JS

Tags: javascript, кэширование, base64

Можно ли как-то кэшировать изображения, добавленные с помощью base64?

Я знаю, что можно кэшировать изображения, которые грузятся по url, но как то же самое сделать для base64?

Comment: А какой смысл их кэшировать?

Comment: Изображение закодированное в base64 - это строка. Такие строки кэшируются средствами JS точно так же, как и любые другие строковые значения.